# Scrolling Yahoo Finance News

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, sentiment-analysis, yahoo-finance

So i'm working on a little project where i scrape yahoo finance news on a specific company and do some data analysis on it to see how news sentiment affects stock performance. I'm trying to scrape and scroll infinitely till it stops however, I'm having trouble trying to scrape past the first scroll.

I'm using selenium to help me with that. I've been searching everywhere for help but it seems like because the news results are loaded incrementally each time you scroll down, it complicates things much more.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Web scrapper for infinite scrolling page 
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/company/press-releases?p=company"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)  # Allow 2 seconds for the web page to open
scroll_pause_time = 2 
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web

i = 1
   
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

##### Extract Article Titles #####
titles = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
for t in soup.find_all(class_="Cf"):
    a_tag = t.find("a", class_="Fw(b)")
    if a_tag:
        text = a_tag.text
        titles.append(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not best automation practice in selenium

For multiple reasons, logging into sites like Gmail and Facebook using WebDriver is not recommended. Aside from being against the usage terms for these sites (where you risk having the account shut down), it is slow and unreliable.

The ideal practice is to use the APIs that email providers offer, or in the case of Facebook the developer tools service which exposes an API for creating test accounts, friends, and so forth. Although using an API might seem like a bit of extra hard work, you will be paid back in speed, reliability, and stability. The API is also unlikely to change, whereas webpages and HTML locators change often and require you to update your test framework.

Logging in to third-party sites using WebDriver at any point of your test increases the risk of your test failing because it makes your test longer. A general rule of thumb is that longer tests are more fragile and unreliable.

WebDriver implementations that are W3C conformant also annotate the navigator object with a WebDriver property so that Denial of Service attacks can be mitigated.

Comment: ahhh thanks for this, i'm not too familiar with scraping, so i thought as a small little side project, this would be enough, but thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

This sample code is from a project that I worked on a short time ago.  Hopefully it helps you get going in the right direction.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.cnbc.com/finance/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))
substring = 'https://www.cnbc.com/'

df = ['review']
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    #print(link['href'])
    if (link['href'].find(substring) == 0): 
        # append
        df.append(link['href'])
        
        #print(link['href'])
        
        
        #list(df)
        # convert list to data frame
        df = DataFrame(df)
        #type(df)
        #list(df)
        
        # add column name
        df.columns = ['review']
        df.columns
        
        from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
        sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
        df['sentiment'] = df['review'].apply(lambda x: sid.polarity_scores(x))
        def convert(x):
            if x < 0:
                return "negative"
            elif x > .2:
                return "positive"
            else:
                return "neutral"
                df['result'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x:convert(x['compound']))
                df['result']
            
                df_final = pd.merge(df['review'], df['result'], left_index=True, right_index=True)
                df_final
```

Result:

```
                                               review   result
0                                              review  neutral
1                      https://www.cnbc.com/business/  neutral
2   https://www.cnbc.com/2021/02/22/chinas-foreign...  neutral
3   https://www.cnbc.com/2021/02/22/chinas-foreign...  neutral
4                  https://www.cnbc.com/evelyn-cheng/  neutral
..                                                ...      ...
89                        https://www.cnbc.com/banks/  neutral
90  https://www.cnbc.com/2021/02/17/wells-fargo-sh...  neutral
91                   https://www.cnbc.com/technology/  neutral
92  https://www.cnbc.com/2021/02/17/lakestar-found...  neutral
93               https://www.cnbc.com/finance/?page=2  neutral

[94 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

by pressing space on your keyboard while on any webpage you automatically scroll down. Simulate that in selenium using the Keys functionalities

driver.send_keys(Keys.SPACE) something like that